# sql - aggregation issue

Tags: sql, having

I have two tables in my DB - products & orders. An order can only be of one kind of product.

Here's the basic idea:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is a query that given a copmany_id returns all the products (from that company) that have less than 10 orders (including 0)

my query looks like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   product p,
       order o
WHERE  p.company_id =?
       AND o.product_id = p.id
GROUP  BY p.id
HAVING Count(o.id) < 10
ORDER  BY p.id DESC
```

The query works fine for products which have 0 < orders but doesn't return ones with 0 orders. What do I need to do to return them as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `INNER JOINING` your two tables, which means that only those products are returned for which there is at least one order.
You will need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the order table:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   product p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN order o
                    ON o.product_id = p.id
WHERE  p.company_id = ?
GROUP  BY p.id
HAVING Count(o.id) < 10
ORDER  BY p.id DESC
```

A left outer join will return every record on the left-hand side of the `JOIN` operation at least once, regardless if there is a matching record to the right-hand side of the `JOIN` operation.

Answer (score 1):

try left outer join

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   product p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN order o
                    ON o.product_id = p.id
WHERE  p.company_id =?
GROUP  BY p.id
HAVING Count(o.id) < 10
ORDER  BY p.id DESC
```

[See this example for left outer join](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/AnExampleofaLeftOuterJoin1.htm)

Comment: is there any way to avoid a join in this case?

Comment: you have to use join.. what you have used in your query is also a join, but that is inner join